# How one thread monitor other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, heartbeat

I am trying to understand how "heartbeat threads" work (at conceptual level, to begin with).

How is it possible that "Thread-A" checks status of "Thread-B" (in Java), and accordingly update status to some server (which expects Thread-B to be alive). What mechanism would Thread-A do to get status for Thread-B?

Comment: Did this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399860/heartbeat-implementation-with-thread-sleep. If not, did you search the web or this site?  I got many hits for that topic.

Answer (score 4):

In general, one thread can only test whether another is alive, by calling [`isAlive()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--)

However, many threads can be "alive" but in a state where they aren't doing anything useful. To detect that, you need to have the thread publish regular updates about its activity. Then a monitoring thread can detect whether the expected activity is no longer occurring.

For example, a batch process might update a shared counter each time it processes a record. Another thread can read this counter, and if it doesn't increase for some time, assume that the process is hung.

In production systems, the conventional solution is to instrument your process with calls to a metrics library. The library would make this information available to a time series database collector. Notification and visualization systems would use data from the time series database to send alerts or display graphs.

Software recommendations are off-topic, but one instantiation of this stack would be [Micrometer](http://micrometer.io/) to collect metrics, [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to collect and store them, and [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to display them.